# Output SQL Query (not Query Results) using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Is there an easy way to display the SQL query (not query results) being passed into a MySQL database using PHP to see if there are any SQL syntax errors? For instance, say I want to the query for the find user function below. For this, I have to modify the three different pages to see the final sql query by echoing it out. Is there a simpler way to do this.

```
// PAGE 1 --- used to find a user on a webpage
$users = User::find_user();

// PAGE 2 --- used as a function to find a user on a class page
static public function find_all_userid() {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid=" . $_SESSION['userid'] . " LIMIT 1";
return static::find_by_sql($sql);
}

// PAGE 3 --- this is in the "database" class
static public function find_by_sql($sql) {
$result = self::$database->query($sql);
if(!$result) {
   exit("Database query failed.");
}
$object_array = [];
while($record = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $object_array[] = static::instantiate($record);
}
$result->free();
return $object_array;
}
```

Comment: `echo` maybe? :)

Comment: What method are you using to generate and submit the query?

Comment: die('Select * From Users Where id = ' . $id ) ??

Comment: depends how you make the query. Show us your code please.

Comment: Why? If you don't get an error back the syntax is good.

Comment: @PaulCampbell maybe for debugging - if the system reports a syntax error then it would be useful to see what query the code generated, then the error can be found and fixed more easily.

Comment: Catch the error and you can log both the error string and the query.

Comment: @PaulCampbell Maybe you should write up an answer on how to do that then, seems to fit the bill, if both can be captured at once. Unless OP wants the query to be visible anytime, not just when an error occurs.